# Rank of matrix contradicts the number of independent columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, linear-algebra, rank

I have 50x49 matrix `A` that has 49 linearly independent columns. However, my software (octave) tells me its rank is 44:

[image]

1. Is it due to some computational error? If so, then how to prevent such errors?
2. If the software was able to correctly calculate `rref(A)`, then why did it fail with `rank(A)`? Does it mean that calculating `rank(A)` is more error prone than calculating `rref(A)`, or vice versa? I mean `rref(A)` actually tells you the rank, but here's a contradiction.

---

P.S. I've checked, Python makes the same error.

---

**EDIT 1**: Here is the [matrix](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FTVdmk1LHHvbsD8FM5Nkd_Y-Iu9IrT81/view?usp=sharing) `A` itself. The first 9 columns were given. The rest was obtained with polynomial features.

---

**EDIT 2**: I was able to found a similar issue. Here is 10x10 [matrix](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_llD9clwKV2-rjKJtyvVtCU2S0sc-Cmr/view?usp=sharing) `B` of rank 10 (and octave calculates its rank correctly). However, octave says that `rank(B * B) = 9` which is impossible.

Comment: How can we tell if you don't provide the matrix...? Or a smaller one that reproduces the problem

Comment: @LuisMendo, Hello! You're right. I've attached the matrix in the edit. Unfortunately I can't find a shorter one, because I've encountered the problem for the first time.

Comment: @LuisMendo, I was able to find a shorter matrix ```B``` (see **EDIT 2**). It doesn't actually represent the same issue, since ```rank(B)``` doesn't contradict the number of its independent columns, but that's wrong behavior as well.

Comment: This seems to be a numerical problem, as you suspected. The condition number of the matrix is large (see [`cond`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cond.html))

Comment: @LuisMendo, But why on Earth did it calculate ```rref(A)``` correctly? If it's due to some numerical error, then shouldn't octave be wrong in both cases ```rref(A)``` and ```rank(A)```?

Comment: The algorithm used by [`rank`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rank.html#mw_6370db84-3c18-4616-8105-d8220f6f6b4b) seems to be different from that used by [`rref`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rref.html#mw_2235e735-9cfc-4d3a-b89d-5832e0b05097): SVD vs Gauss-Jordan elimination with partial pivoting. So they may have different performance regarding numerical accuracy

Comment: @LuisMendo, That makes sense now. But isn't it a big problem? I mean the matrix should be invertible, but it's not. Is it a common problem in practice? Or it just doesn't cause too much harm due to existence of pseudo-inverse?

Comment: _The matrix should be invertible, but it's not_. That distinction is clear-cut in theory, but not so in practice. A matrix with large _condition number_ (as in your example) is invertible but with numerical instabilities. Think of that as `B` having a very small determinant, so it's _almost_ singular. As result, the inverse matrix will be computed with bad accuracy. Or it could be that `B` is "really" singular, but small numerical errors from previous computations make it look non-singular... how could you tell? Yes, this is well known. In general, avoid matrices with large condition number

Comment: @LuisMendo, Thank you a lot for the explanation. Because I was about to start thinking it was me who was wrong, not a computer :) Btw, what should I do to the post? Don't you want to leave an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted a comment because felt it didn't fully answer your question. But following your suggestion I've posted it as an answer

Comment: @LuisMendo, No, the answer is perfect! It's just that I don't know how one can avoid matrices with large condition number if such a matrix was given to you by the real world problem itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction between an invertible matrix (i.e. full rank) and a non-invertible one is clear-cut in theory, but not so in practice. A matrix `B` with large [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices) (as in your example) can be inverted, but computing the inverse is numerically unstable. It roughly corresponds to `B` having a determinant that is "small" (using an appropriate, relative measure of "small"), so the matrix is *almost* singular. As a result, the inverse matrix will be computed with bad accuracy. In your example `B`, the condition number (computed with [`cond`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cond.html)) is `2.069e9`.

Another way to look at this is: when the condition number is large, it well could be that `B` is "really" singular, but small numerical errors from previous computations make it look barely non-singular. So you can't be sure.

The `rank` and `rref` functions use different algorithms (singular-value decomposition for [`rank`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rank.html#mw_6370db84-3c18-4616-8105-d8220f6f6b4b), Gauss-Jordan elimination with partial pivoting for [`rref`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rref.html#mw_2235e735-9cfc-4d3a-b89d-5832e0b05097)). For well-behaved matrices the numerical errors will be small in both cases, and the results will be consistent. But for a bad-conditioned matrix the numerical errors will be large and potentially different in each case, giving inconsistent results.

This is a well known issue with numerical algebra. In general, avoid inverting matrices with large condition number.